# sqlcmd returns no values on MSI Installer Project, while it returns normally values outside the installer class

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-installer

Iam having a installer project, which has to find out which SQL Instances installed on the local machine. This happens in the installer class.

The command i use is as follwoing;

`sqlcmd -S Localhost\SQLEXPRESS -Q "DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE(Value nvarchar(100), InstanceNames nvarchar(100), Data nvarchar(100)); Insert into @GetInstances EXECUTE xp_regread  @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server', @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'; Select InstanceNames from @GetInstances ;"`

when i excute it from my cmd or as bat file, it works fine. From the installer class at Commit or before or even after install , i get 0 rows back. i don't understand why? what is the difference!

can anyone help me with that? Thanks in Advance

edit1:
I used `reg query ""HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL` to find out which intances are installed and i got an error that this key was not found. it works normally outside the installer class.

Comment: What is the connections string?  Did you try the query using SQL Server Management Studio?  The database (MDF) file may not be attached to server or you may not have the credentials to write to file.  Check the LDF log files.

Comment: Keep in mind that the installer is executed by Windows under a dedicate account, so anything (sqlcmd and more) can behave differently.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Can i define the user that starts the installer?